# undefined reference to `htole32'

Tags: c

error occurs while compiling the following c code on CentOS release 4.3.

```
#include <endian.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    union {
        uint32_t u32;
        uint8_t arr[4];
    } x;

    x.arr[0] = 0x11;   
    x.arr[1] = 0x22;
    x.arr[2] = 0x33;
    x.arr[3] = 0x44;  

    printf("x.u32 = 0x%x\n", x.u32);
    printf("htole32(x.u32) = 0x%x\n", htole32(x.u32));
    printf("htobe32(x.u32) = 0x%x\n", htobe32(x.u32));

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Details of compiling errors:

> $ gcc a.c  /tmp/ccki8bVg.o(.text+0x3a): In function `main': :
>   undefined reference to`htole32' /tmp/ccki8bVg.o(.text+0x58): In
>   function `main': : undefined reference to`htobe32' collect2: ld
>   returned 1 exit status

It seems that there isn't htole32 and htobe32 on my server.

> $ man htole32 
>   No manual entry for htole32

Comment: Check your include and library flags in the IDE (or your command line compiler flags). This simply means that the compile cannot find the includes/sources/libraries your function is referenced from. May be the location in your server is invalid/has typo in the path name. At least, put your 1) Command line build statement with flags or 2) IDE configuration for includes, sources, and libraries in the code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The manual page](http://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/3/htole32/) actually has:

```
#define _BSD_SOURCE
```

before the `#include <endian.h>`. It only has that in the top section though, not in the example program below. Of course, since your target system doesn't even have the manual page, that might imply it has a runtime environment which doesn't implement this (non-standard) part.

Comment: Got it! These functions were added to glibc in version 2.9, while mine is 2.3.