# ./configure don't find htobe32

Tags: linux, gcc, embedded, configure

working on an embedded Linux i get a strange error.

```
conftest.c:37:10: warning: implicit declaration of function 'htobe32' 
[-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
n_be  = htobe32(n_uint32);<br>
/tmp/cckbgVe5.o: In function main:
conftest.c:(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `htobe32'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I guess anything is proper installed, because i can find the endian-Headers. Although, i don't know which Library is actually needed.

```
/usr/share/man/man3/endian.3.gz
/usr/include/bits/endian.h
/usr/include/linux/byteorder/little_endian.h
/usr/include/linux/byteorder/big_endian.h
/usr/include/endian.h
```

This is my path:
`echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bi/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl`

Is a lib missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [undefined reference to \`htole32'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26713198/undefined-reference-to-htole32)

Comment: Nah, i have glibc 2.23-1.
But i found this:
 #if defined(\_\_linux\_\_) || defined(\_\_CYGWIN\_\_)
#       include <endian.h>
Maybe, the precompiler flag isn't set. How can i check?

Comment: @b-boy: `cpp -dM </dev/null`